# Multiple connections using OpenSSL

Tags: java, c++, ssl, tcp, applet

I am trying to connect a Java applet client to a Cpp server using OpenSSL.  It works fine until I make a second connection then I can't send any data to the server or the client and the client freezes.  When I use s_server multiple connections don't work either.  Is it just a fact I can't connect multiple connections to the same server or is there some method I can use to fix things.  Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case where you're using (blocking) `java.io` instead of `java.nio`, thus causing your main application thread to freeze until the second connection is satisfied. [Here's a tutorial](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/11/03/ssl-nio.html) on setting up multiple SSL connections using the latter.

Good luck with your application!